# QML - Possible to display 3 listViews in a single view

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

Is it possible to display multiple listViews in a single page?

I have 3 seperate list views and I'd like to display them on a single page and I'm struggling to lay them out. They all overlap each other.

Simple example of the layout:

```
ListView {
    id: listOne
    property string headertitle: "list one header"
    spacing: 5
    header: headerComponent
    model: ListOneModel
}

ListView {
    id: listTwo
    property string headertitle: "list two header"
    spacing: 5
    header: headerComponent
    model: ListTwoModel
}

ListView {
    id: listThree
    property string headertitle: "list three header"
    spacing: 5
    header: headerComponent
    model: ListThreeModel
}
```

Comment: Yes, is possible. If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve], in addition to indicating how you want them to be placed on the page.

Comment: How do you want them to show: all in a column or in a row?

Comment: @eyllanesc 3 rows, full width, 1 list view per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Column](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 180; height: 200
    id: root

    Column {
        ListView {
            width: root.width; height: root.height/3
            model: myModel
            delegate: Text {
                text: name + ": " + number
            }
        }

        ListView {
            width: root.width; height: root.height/3

            model: myModel
            delegate: Text {
                text: name + ": " + number
            }
        }

        ListView {
            width: root.width; height: root.height/3

            model: myModel
            delegate: Text {
                text: name + ": " + number
            }
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: myModel
        ListElement {
            name: "Bill Smith"
            number: "555 3264"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "John Brown"
            number: "555 8426"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Sam Wise"
            number: "555 0473"
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a single scrollable list.  The OP asked for multiple parallel listviews...  Therefore the other answer got my positive vote.

Answer (score 7):

Note that a `Column` with 3 `ListView`s in it will give you a rather odd scrolling experience, where you wouldn't be scrolling it all as if it is a single view, but scroll individual list views.

As long as you don't go crazy with the model sizes (and I mean like thousands), you can simply use a `Flickable` with a `Column` with 3 repeaters in it. This will give you a single continuous column you could scroll through.

The reason this solution will not be efficient for thousands of model items is that under normal circumstances, list view creates and destroys delegates as needed, and keeps created only what is visible on screen plus some optional caching. Whereas this solution will create all items, in order to get one uniform column to scroll through.

Here is a quick example demonstrating the 2 distinct behaviors:

[image]

```
  Row {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Flickable {
      width: parent.width * .5
      height: parent.height
      flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
      contentHeight: contentItem.childrenRect.height
      Column {
        spacing: 2
        Repeater {
          model: 5
          delegate: Rectangle { width: 100; height: 100; color: "red" }
        }
        Repeater {
          model: 5
          delegate: Rectangle { width: 100; height: 100; color: "green" }
        }
        Repeater {
          model: 5
          delegate: Rectangle { width: 100; height: 100; color: "blue" }
        }
      }
    }
    Column {
      width: parent.width * .5
      height: parent.height
      spacing: 2
      ListView {
        spacing: 2
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height / 3
        model: 5
        clip: true
        delegate: Rectangle { width: 100; height: 100; color: "red" }
      }
      ListView {
        spacing: 2
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height / 3
        model: 5
        clip: true
        delegate: Rectangle { width: 100; height: 100; color: "green" }
      }
      ListView {
        spacing: 2
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height / 3
        model: 5
        clip: true
        delegate: Rectangle { width: 100; height: 100; color: "blue" }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is great.  Thanks for providing both behaviors.  I can see a useage in my app for both.